# Most efficient way to store and access image resources in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf, image, performance, resources

Purpose of question:

I am starting an application that will be taking images provided by users and letting them play around with them, in 3d view via Viewport3D and Viewport2DVisual3D...

I will need to be switching different images inside ViewPort3D quite frequently - I am going for a sort of framelike/comic effect in 2.5D - for approximate estimate of scale I expect to be displaying 10 to 50 images at a time, and switching up to 10 of these at intervals as fast as 0.2 seconds. The library of images from which these will be selected may contain several thousand images.

Question:

For performance in WPF what is the best way for me to store these images and best way to access them for quickly switching from one to the other? Should I just let the user point me to their picture folder, or is there some way to "precompile" the image library for faster access?

Below is a snippet of XAML on how these will be used, though of course the application will generate all these objects in code past prototype stage.

```
 <Viewport3D>
        <Viewport3D.Camera>
            <PerspectiveCamera Position="60, 50, 100" FieldOfView="90"   LookDirection="0,0,-1" />                
        </Viewport3D.Camera>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D>                
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="40,40,0 40,0,0 80,0,0 80,40,0"
                    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"  Brush="Transparent"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <Image Name="ImagePlaceHolder1" Source="Textures/Image1.gif"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D>

        <Viewport2DVisual3D>                
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
                <MeshGeometry3D Positions="40,80,0 40,40,0 80,40,0 80,80,0"
                    TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,1 1,0" TriangleIndices="0 1 2 0 2 3"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Geometry>
            <Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
                <DiffuseMaterial Viewport2DVisual3D.IsVisualHostMaterial="True"  Brush="Transparent"/>
            </Viewport2DVisual3D.Material>
            <Image Name="ImagePlaceHolder2"  Source="Textures/Image2.jpg"/>
        </Viewport2DVisual3D>
```